# What are other wordings for "to enter the balcony"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, idiomatic-language

What are other wordings for "to enter the balcony" (by walking)? As far as I know, "step" with some preposition (maybe "on", "onto" ?) can be used to express that, right?

Comment: *Go/get out on the balcony, or go/get onto balcony* can work there. Step onto the balcony can also fit properly. Adding "out" before "onto" can make sense only if you are inside and you need to *step **out** and go **onto** the balcony*. To answer your question, it wouldn't be much similar to "step" assuming you know it means "to make/take a step." I think *"go or get"* would express something similar to "enter." But if someone wants you to get onto a balcony, you will say *"**come** here **onto** the balcony."*

Comment: Can you provide additional context?  There are times when a person could run onto a balcony, fall onto a balcony, dance onto the balcony, etc.  There's not enough info to properly narrow the options.

Comment: I need to express "to enter the balcony" by walking.

Comment: Do you say "to go/get on the balcony"?